# Vim plugin for browsing through Rake or Capistrano tasks

Tags: vim, rake, capistrano, macvim, ctags

I'm looking for a plugin for Vim that lets me browse through all my Rake tasks and Capistrano tasks in a file. Does this exists or could Ctags be extended easily to make this work in Taglist or NERD_tree?

I'm using MacVim with Janus

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that's working for me. I added this to my $HOME/.ctags

```
--regex-Ruby=/(^|^[[:blank:]]*)task[ \t\:']*([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/\2/t,tasks/
--regex-Ruby=/(^|^[[:blank:]]*)namespace[ \t\:]*([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/\2/n,namespaces/
```

And this to my .vimrc

```
let g:tagbar_type_ruby = {
    \ 'ctagstype' : 'Ruby',
    \ 'kinds'     : [
        \ 'c:classes',
        \ 'f:methods',
        \ 'F:singleton methods',
        \ 'm:modules',
        \ 'n:namespaces',
        \ 't:tasks'
    \ ]
\ }
```